# How to submit a form with javascript without having the button trigger a new page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a simpel form that I would like to submit with Ajax. It seems that regardless how I approach this, the form keeps insisting to refresh the page.

I would like the form to be submitted with a GET request, submitted with javascript, because I need a js response back from the server.

```
<div id='form_wrapper'>
  <div class='gradient'></div>
   <form action='' class='my-form' method='get' name='my-form'>
    <div class='header'>
      <h1>Submit this form</h1>
      <span>Please fill out all fields, and then submit the form.</span>
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
      <input class='input full_name' name='full_name' placeholder='Your full name' type='text'>
      <div class='full_name-icon input-icon'></div>
      <input class='input address' name='address' placeholder='Your full address' type='text'>
      <div class='address-icon input-icon'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='form-footer'>
      <input class='button' name='submit' type='submit' value='SUBMIT'>
      <input class='help' name='submit' type='submit' value='HELP?'>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Also, I would like my submit button to not look like it is being pushed down - meaning that I would like to avoid having that blue border around the button once it has been pushed. I usually avoid the blue border by letting my buttons have `href='javascript:void(0)'`, but as this is a form button I don't suppose I can apply my own `href`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, i don't think you should have 2 submit buttons, but have an other mechanism in place, for the two different submit actions, however, that aside, i'll give you a jQuery answer since it's faster:

```
$(document).on('submit','.my-form',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          url: "processing_page.php",
          type : 'get',
          data: { name : $('.full_name').val(), address: $('.address').val },
          dataType: 'json'
        }).success(function(data){
           // do something here 
           console.log(data); //this is an object in my example
        });
    });
```

You'll also need a php processing page (named processing_page.php in my example) to get back some data. For example (didn't go through all the verification steps on either side, but you'll get the gist of it):

```
<?php

$myData = ['name' => '', 'address' => ''];

$name = $_POST['name'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

$myData['name'] = $name;
$myData['address'] = $address;

echo json_encode($myData);

?>
```

Reason for the long answer is so that you can verify your code at the basic level.
Hope i didn't make any typos.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/submit/):

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
event.preventDefault();
});
```

`event.preventDefault()` stops the submit from triggering a new page.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following if you're using vanilla JavaScript;

```js
function myFunc(){
  alert(1);
}
```

```html
<form id="formID" onsubmit="myFunc(); return false;">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

When you click the submit button, it will activate the myFunc() JavaScript function and using return false in this manner will prevent the page from being changed. Then simply call document.getElementById('formID') to load the form details up. Alternatively you can use an active selector or jQuery $("#formID").

Happy Coding!